# Digital audio does not work on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, audio, macbook-pro, digital-audio

I have a MacBook Pro (8,2). Using a TOSLINK cable I have no digital output. Oddly enough, sometime I can hear a glitch when I plug in the cable or when I give it a gentle wiggle.

My guess is that the output is not correctly detecting that I have a digital link. So is there a way to force digital audio output on a MacBook Pro?

Some say that in the `Audio MIDI Setup` there is an option but I can't find it. I am running OS X 10.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

There's an actual mechanical switch in the jack. If the Mac detects a TOSLINK cable it'll switch to digital optical output – if it's just a regular 1/8" headphone connector it'll switch back.

Since you mentioned you have to wiggle a bit this means your jack is broken and you will have to get the jack or even the whole logic board fixed. This seems to appear quite often – some users also mention that their MacBook Pro gets stuck in digital mode and they have to use a paperclip to bring it back to analog.